# google cloud shell terminal WARNING: psql major version 9.6, server major version 12

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, psql

I'm trying to use google cloud shell on browser and have the latest psql 12.3 on my win 10 PC before I had 12.1 but, I updated to see if the issue will go away but, its still saying my machine has 9.6 The dependency I created on google cloud is 12 so, I'm not sure why its giving me this warning.

I'm useing 
1vcpu,
Memory 3.75 GB
SSD storage 10 GB

```
 CLOUD SHELL
 Terminal


psql (9.6.17, server 12.1)
WARNING: psql major version 9.6, server major version 12.1
     Some psql features might not work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that PostgreSQL **client** version is 9.6 and that PostgreSQL **server** version is 12.1.

You can only use  `psql` 9.6 features and you can still use most server 12.1 features.

If you don't want this warning you need to install PostgreSQL **client** version 12.

Comment: How do I install version 12 in google cloud shell ?